# Format of data-time storage

Tags: android, time

I am sending Sms from emulator control to emulator.. but it shows time in some different format. Can Anyone Help me understand that code or format. Here is the pic

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably using the [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) function for accessing the time, what returns the current time in milliseconds. If you want your date formatted, then use:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
String timeString = new Date(time).toLocaleString();
```

Or if you just need the time part from it, like in the example you have shown, then:

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
String timeString = formater.format(new Date(time)); //time is the current time as a long value;
```

---

### As for how the date is stored:

System.currentTimeMillis()

> Returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current
>   time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

This means, that the long number you get, is the passed milliseconds since January 1, 1970.
From this value its pretty easy to count the current year, month day, etc...

As you can see in my previous example, you can conver this long value to a Date object, by passing it to the Date() constructor, and you can convert a Date object to a long value using:

```
long time = dateObject.getTime();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sir, the thing is I want to understand this format that how  date is stored in this format. Actually when I get date from database it too comes in this format & my main motive is to convert the real date in this format & store it in data base. Hope I am able to Explain myself

Comment: Oh i see. I extend my answer :)

Comment: @Aexyn just store that cryptic number in your database, makes sorting easier and you can still convert it to a readable format once you display it (even SQLite can convert it: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html if you divide it by 1000)

Comment: @bali182 Great Sir.. I converted it and it comes nearby to that code. :) thanx alot